# SQL Select with Replace/Case doesn't work in access forms (syntax error)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use a combo box to filter a report. My "log type" values are saved in the table as 1, 2 (number data type). However, I want the combo box to populate with 'a', 'b' instead of 1, 2.

I've tried the following SQL statements in the "Row Source" under "Data" tab for the combo box:

```
SELECT [qryLog].[log_type], CASE WHEN [qryLog].[log_type] = 1 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END FROM [qryLog]
```

This gives the following error:
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN [log_type] = 1 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END'

I also tried this:

```
SELECT [qryLog].[log_type], REPLACE([log_type],1,'a') FROM qryLog;
```

This doesn't do anything at all, the drop-down choices are still 1, 2 (I would expect it to be 'a' and 2).

Is there something wrong with my SQL expressions or does Access not allow this type or operation. I'm using Access 2013.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track, perhaps you even solved it already.

But, the most likely issue here that you're facing is that your combo box is referencing the incorrect column after your query was changed.

For instance:

For Combo1, in the Data Tab the Row Source is like:

`SELECT [qryLog].[log_type], REPLACE([log_type],1,'a') FROM qryLog;`

But since that reference is not what you are looking for anymore, you want the replaced value. You're probably looking for this:

`SELECT REPLACE([log_type],1,'a') AS [log_type] FROM qryLog;`

That will obviously only cover your 1's, but you probably get the idea.

**Update:**

`SELECT Replace(Replace([qryLog].[log_type],1,'a'),2,'b') AS Whatever FROM qryLog`

This assumes you are using Row Source and not Control Source as the method of populating the Combo Box. Screen Cap below:

[image]

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think we're getting close, how can I change the value that the combo box is referencing. If I try your code above, it gives me a "circular reference" error, I think i need to have AS New_Column, but somehow reference that New_Column in the combo box as the source of data instead of the log_type.